# How can I add an image decal to a 3D model in WPF Viewport3D/Helix Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I am working with a Viewport3D in WPF (C#.Net), using Helix 3D toolkit as a helper (using SharpDX), and would like to add an image as a decal/texture to a 3D model that I have loaded in the viewport. I can load a model, but I cannot find any way to edit the model's texture/material.

I have searched for information on textures, materials, and UV mapping, but cannot find any information on how I can add/project an image onto the model's surface.

In the end, I'd like to be able to select a square region of the 3D model and "project" an image to the surface so that the 3D model can then be rotated/zoomed to inspect the overlay(s). Is there an easy way to do that?

3D view of part I'd like to add decal to:
[3D view of part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZpX9.png)

3D model from here (used as example): https://www.artec3d.com/3d-models/fairing

Goal (manually added the image overlay):
[3D view of part with desired overlay result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtIN0.png)

Comment: You need to use some kind of algorithm to generate texture coordinates for the model surface.